# Filter table results based on date entered in angular 6+

Tags: javascript, html, angular, datefilter, tablefilter

My Angular 6 app has a table getting populated with back-end data(coming as JSON).
Further, i have added a input form control of type 'text' to filter results based on text on a particular column. Basically this filter happens on every (keyup) event. 
Now, i need to add an input form control of type 'date' to filter results based on dates within another column of my table.

Template markup i am using for text filtering -

```
   <p>
      <input
        #query
        (keyup)="filter(query.value)"
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Search Venues by Name...">
  </p>
```

Event handler i use for this filtering in my corresponding component -

```
filter(query: string) {
    this.filteredVenues = (query) ?
      this.venues.filter(v => v.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) :
      this.venues;
  }
```

So, my text filtering is working fine. I need assistance to how i can do the same filtering if i input date. Date format in my JSON looks like below,

```
2019-01-28T01:26:12.738Z
2018-07-15T00:10:10.749Z
2019-01-28T01:21:06.223Z
```

I tried going with the same approach as above(text filtering) but the complications i face are -

1. Keyup event will not trigger
2. date format incompatibility between what i input and what is stored in backend JSON

Here is the code which i wrote for date filtering. I am sure there is a lot i need to modify on the below.

Template -

```
<input
    #queryDate
    (keyup)="filterDate(queryDate.value)"
    type="date"
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="Search Venues by Date...">
```

Component.ts -

```
filterDate(queryDate: date) {
    this.filteredVenues = (queryDate) ?
    this.venues.filter(v => v.datecreated.includes(queryDate)) :
    this.venues;
  }
```

Can anyone guide me as to how to get this working(filtering) for the above mentioned date formats?

Comment: Instead of keyup event, try to use change event: `(change)="filterDate(queryDate.value)"`

Comment: @JoHTVS thanks... Let me check that out

Comment: Do you want to filter only by date without time?

Comment: @Ininiv I do need to filter by time as well. I figured out a way to filter by date. I posted the solution below. Could you please modify it to filter by time as well? It will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
filterDate(queryDate: date) {
this.filteredVenues = (queryDate) ?
this.venues.filter(v => new Date(v.datecreated) == queryDate) :
this.venues;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below and it worked -

Template code -

```
<input
  #queryDate
  (change)="filterDate(queryDate.valueAsDate)"
  type="date"
  class="form-control"
  placeholder="Search Venues by Date...">
```

TypeScript code -

```
filterDate(queryDate: any) {
    this.filteredVenues = (queryDate) ?
    this.venues.filter(v => v.datecreated.includes(queryDate.toISOString().split('T')[0])) :
    this.venues;
  }
```